# Powershell convertto-html break image in new Outlook with Copilot

Tags: html, azure, powershell, automation, base64

I create a powershell 7.2 azure automation runbook who use microsoft graph to put some users in Azure groups and activate the new Outlook Experience for Copilot.

That part work well.

The problem is the confirmation email i send with powershell and microsoft graph with Send-MgUserMail .

This email resume the listing of all the users who has been go throught the runbook to get the new Outlook Experience.

In the email i show the image of the user (get with mggraph and converted to base64) with somes informations .

In Outlook without Copilot and the new experience activated, all the image show OK in the email.

In Outlook with the new experience and Copilot, most images are OK but the one who are generated with convertto-html dont show up.

Here the code where i get the image:

```
Try{  Get-MgUserPhotoContent -UserId $u -OutFile "c:\temp\$u.jpg" -ErrorAction stop
$image = Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\$u.jpg" -ErrorAction stop
$ImageBits = [Convert]::ToBase64String((Get-Content $image -AsByteStream))
}
Catch{"No photo found for $u"}
if($image -eq $null){
  $ImageHTML = "<img height=72 width=72 src=data&colon;image/jpg;base64,$($noimagebase64)/>"
}
else{
$ImageHTML = "<img height=72 width=72 src=data&colon;image/jpg;base64,$($ImageBits)/>"
}
if(($getnoe).OneWinNativeOutlookEnabled -eq "True"){
$check = "<img height=25 width=25 src=data&colon;image/png;base64,$($minigreencheck)/>"
}
else{$check ="FALSE"}
```

After that i create an array with the user photo and some informations like the device name et license name

```
 $u | ForEach-Object {
    $userstatus += [pscustomobject]@{
      Photo = $ImageHTML ;
      Name = $username ;
      Email = ($u) -join";";
      Outlook = $check ;
        License = $getlicense.SkuPartNumber -join";";
        UserDevice = $device.DeviceName ;
        Groupe_Policy = $Groupe_Policy ;
    }
  }
```

And at the end i convert that array into HTML table to put in my email

```
$tableuser = $userstatus| ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -As Table | Out-String
$tableuser = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($tableuser )
```

So here is the exemple where it work well, we can see the user photo (masked here) and the green check mark as well as the copilot logo at the top.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbbc8.png)

And here is in OWA and Outlook with new experience where all image are broken (the one i convertto-html) but the copilot logo at the top is OK. So base64 image is supported in both version.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz4qx.png)

I know CID can be use to but i already code everything and its work well with most outlook version.

Thank you!

I inspected the code of the page in the  browser to see any differences but it just seeem that OWA and the new Outlook use something different to render the HTML image in base64 with convertto-html in powershell. So im not sure what is different since the other base64 images are ok.

EDIT 01:

Here an exemple of a base 64 image that work well in both Outlook and OWA version in my HTML template (The copilot logo at the top of email). Note that i don't use "" in the HTML anywhere because the Send-MgMailUser give me an error when encoding the body of the email.

I remove some of the base64 string because im limited by 30000 caracters here in the post.

```
$body = "
<style>
body{
  padding:20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.hr1 {
    border: 0;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.000), rgba(109, 213, 250, 1.000), rgba(41, 128, 185, 1.000));
}
hr {
  margin: 30px 0;
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(transparent), to(transparent), color-stop(50%, black));
}

  <td align=center><img height=30% width=30% src=data:image/png;base64,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...></img></td>
```

Here is the part where i put my variable array converted to HTML in the html email body:

```
<table border=0 style=undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 100px align=center>

    <tbody>

      <tr>
      
      <td width=100></td>
        <td >

        <br>Hello $userdisplayname,<br><br>

        The new Outlook experience is now activated for:<br><br><br> <center>$tableuser</center> <br><br>

        Thank you,<br><br>

        Have a nice day,<br><br>

        Team Azure.<br>
        <br>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

EDIT 02:

Here the code in the browser (edge) in OWA for the copilot logo that work in any version (base64 image code truncated for caracters limitation in post)

```
<img data-imagetype="DataUri" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADcCAYAAAA1H+4TAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAABmJLR0QAAAAAAAD5Q.....dXpJqLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" height="30%" width="30%">
```

Here the code in the browser (edge) in OWA for a broken image (base64 image code truncated for caracters limitation in post)

```
<img data-imagetype="DataUri" src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT/2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFB....UAFFFFAH//2Q==/" height="72" width="72">
```

Comment: Can you add the html source for an image that works, vs an image that doesn’t? At the very least I’d try quoting your html attributes (```height=“72”```) - it’s not *mandatory*, but it’s *recommended* by W3C, and I’d put a space between ```…$($noimagebase64) />``` as it’s ambiguous whether the ```/``` is part of the attribute value, or the html markup. Might not fix your problem, but doesn’t hurt to try…

Comment: Hi @mclayton, thank you for your reply. I add an EDIT 01 in the post to anwser your question. I try the space at the end of ``` /``` but no chance. Have a nice day!

Comment: Until a few years ago I couldn't even get a base64 image to display correct in Outlook (it wasn't supported). That it works in the current client version surprises me... my guess is that the new client lacks this feature just as the old client did for years.

Comment: Hi @bluuf , that was my first idea but after i realise that others base64 images are OK in the new Outlook. Only the one who go throught convertto-html dont work so base64 seem still working. Thank you!